# A question about "Coin Cells And Peak Current Draw" App Note

Tags: battery-operated, decoupling-capacitor, coin-cell

I'm trying to understand this small TI's app note called [Coin Cells And Peak Current Draw](https://www.ti.com/lit/wp/swra349/swra349.pdf), but I don't get it.

This white paper is interested in increasing the battery life of coin-cell-powered systems.
More specifically, embedded systems using an RF module to communicate.

The paper's conclusion is that **adding a decoupling capacitor will increase lifetime**.

To prove their point, they create 2 tests :

1. Without a capacitor
2. With a capacitor

Honestly, I don't understand the results:

1. Without a capacitor
   [image]
2. With a capacitor
   [image]

I just don't see why those images are proving that using a decoupling capacitor is a good idea.
Also, the paper completely ignores the capacitor leakage current.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Your intuition is correct. The capacitor leakage kills that idea. Jack Ganssle debunked this appnote thoroughly in part of his (excellent) series on ultra low power design: http://www.ganssle.com/reports/ultra-low-power-design.html#usingacapacitor. I'm surprised TI still has it up.

Comment: That looks like an answer to me, @Peter.

Comment: Well you got 50 more mAh (OK, 45ish) out of the same cell before the on-load voltage fell to 2V. (I guess they ran the test relatively fast so leakage over the experiment duration was a non-issue)

Answer (score 2):

The load draws a high current spike during 1ms, which makes the voltage drop due to the high internal resistance of the battery. The chip shuts down at some undervoltage threshold, so it will shut down while there is still some juice left in the battery.

If a capacitor is used, and it has much lower internal resistance than the battery, then it will provide the energy for the current spike, and slowly recharge from the battery afterwards. So the voltage will not drop as much, and the chip will not shut down while the battery is still usable.

If this is a low average current application, the capacitor needs to be low leakage. Some electrolytics leakage in the hundreds of nA, but some are much worse, so make sure to select the right one.

If there is no size constraint on the device, two AA batteries instead of a coin cell also solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a low leakage capacitor type like Polypropylene, Polystyrene or Teflon film.  These are bulky, if you have size or weight constraints using a larger cell gives a greater gain.